# Running all PHPUnit tests for a project using Composer

Tags: php, testing, continuous-integration, phpunit, composer-php

I have a set of PHP projects, some of which depend on others. All have PHPUnit tests. All are installable via Composer, and specify their dependencies using a composer.json file. Each project has a phpunit.xml.dist file in their root, which points to a bootsrap file.

Now I have this project Foo that has a number of direct dependencies and several indirect ones. For the CI of Foo, I'd like to run all its tests, and all those of its dependencies.

Is this somehow possible to do via Composer? If not, is there some standard-ish clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer does not help you with any testing.

And I doubt it can be done automatically. You do not know beforehand where the tests for any required library is located. It might even be that the tests are not included in the released library version because they serve not direct purpose.

If you know that all your libraries do have their tests located somewhere, you'd have to code something yourself to collect all these tests in a big meta-testsuite. But I wonder if these would really be helpful.

I am using CI with Jenkins and a handful of internal libraries, and I set up Jenkins to start the tests of a depending library when I change something in a required library. The [dependency graph view plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dependency+Graph+View+Plugin) is helping to manage that.

Answer (score 5):

You could try [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#writing-custom-commands)

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

Or maybe create a [makefile](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) and then call that using composer

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build-all": "make build-all"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you could write a TestSuite that included everything or write a script that recursively drilled down into all the directories to find the tests.

However, typically, you don't run the tests of libraries and dependencies except, perhaps, when you first install them. You don't (read: shouldn't) really change library or dependency code in your application (there are exceptions to this), so once you've installed the dependency and run its tests, assuming they pass, they should always pass because you haven't changed anything.

If you are changing dependency code, you should really do that separately, especially if you own the dependency. I'm assuming you would do this for one of two reason: fix a bug or add a feature. Open up the project/files for your dependency, write one or more tests for the change, make the change, make sure the tests pass, the commit the changes to your dependency. Then have your application pull down the updated dependency.

The tl;dr of it is that you shouldn't be worried about running library or dependency tests because those should be black boxes that you don't touch in your application.

Comment: In my case I own a lot of the dependencies and I am running their tests whenever they get changed. I'm with you that running all tests together is not strictly needed. There however is no harm in doing so, and it would help reassure some people. Keep in mind my question if how to do this, not if I should do it.

Comment: I know you asked how, and I gave a couple of potential options at the beginning of my answer. However, if someone asked me how to put a knife through their hand, I'd still explain why they shouldn't.

That said, if you're doing this to reassure/appease people, perhaps you should have those "some people" read my initial answer so that you don't have to run all those tests. I'm just trying to save you time, stress, and sanity. I feel this is one of those cases where the effort in in not worth there result out.